# Update "Your flagging history" blocked

Tags: bug, flags

In the last days I have flagged questions both in Triage section and directly on questions but in my "Flag summary" the last event is dated to 27th April. Is there a bug that blocks my update or similar? Is there another explanation to that?

Below you can see my Flag Summary and my last actions:
[image: My Flags summary]

[image: My last actions]

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot?

Comment: With nice free hand circles so we know were to look please.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Reviewing != Flagging

Comment: @BDL Not all review are flags, but "Unsalvageable" are. As you can see I have some "Unsalvageable" review yesterday.

Comment: @Terru_theTerror: Not all Unsalvageable's are flags. You have the close-vote privileg, thus only "Rude or abusive", "Spam" and "In need of moderator attention" are flags. Everything else is a close vote which you can find in "Activity" > "Votes" > "Closure".

Comment: This explains perfectly the behaviour, thank @BDL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a very limited set of actions in the Triage review queue will lead to a flag for users with the close-vote privilege (>3k):

"Looks OK" and "Requires Edit" will never lead to a flag.

Unsalvagable: "Rude or abusive", "Spam" and "In need of moderator attention" are flags. Everything else is a close vote (which is not a flag) and can be seen in "Activity" > "Votes" > "Closure".